# Spring Cloud Consul client does not ignore critical services

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

I have implemented a Spring Cloud based application that has the following principal architecture. The `GatewayService` delegates to multiple instances of `HelloService`. I use *Consul* for service discovery. `GatewayService` is implemented in the following way:

```java
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  @LoadBalanced
  public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
    return WebClient.builder();
  }

  @RestController
  static class GateWayController {

    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    private static class Response {
      private String message;
      private String appName;
      private int port;
    }

    @Autowired
    public GateWayController(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
      this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
    }

    @GetMapping("/lbhello")
    public Mono<Response> hello() {
      return webClientBuilder.build()
                             .get()
                             .uri("lb://hello-service/hello")
                             .retrieve()
                             .bodyToMono(Response.class);
    }
  }
}
```

`spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery` and `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` areincluded as a dependencies in `pom.xml`. In `application.yaml` I only set `application.name` and disable *Ribbon*, so that *Spring Cloud Loadbalancer* is used. When I start the `GatewayService` and two instances of `HelloService` everything works as expected. Service calls to the `lbhello` endpoint are delegated alternately to the two `HelloService` instances.

When one instance of `HelloService` is stopped, *Consul* detects that the instance is missing an marks it as *critical*. As a consequence I would expect that the load balancer stops forwarding requests to the non-existing service, at least after some time. But this never happens. Every second service call is delegated to this service instance and consequently fails. When using *Eureka* as a discovery service the registry is adapted and only the remaining `HelloService` is considered for service calls.

Is this the expected behavior for *Consul*? If the answer is yes, is there a Spring Cloud setting to adapt this behavior?

Comment: maybe https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#instance-health-check-for-loadbalancer

Comment: @spencergibb - which one is preferred ? scheduled health checks vs query passing. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Cloud `ConsulDiscoveryClient` loads all service instance by default, regardless of their health state. This behavior can be changed by the following configuration setting:

```
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.query-passing = true
```

With this setting request are not delegated to non-healty instances after some delay.